# How can I use gunicorn with python3.8 instead of python3.9 on mac os x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, gunicorn

I am trying to use Gunicorn to provide a WSGI server for a simple python3 application on mac os X but it's using python2. I tried installing gunicorn with:

```
pip install gunicorn
```

and

```
pip3 install gunicorn
```

which worked but I got a "command not found" error when I tried to run gunicorn (for example with `gunicorn -w 4 echo:app`). I also tried installing gunicorn3 with pip and pip3 and brew but got an error with each. I was able to get gunicorn to install and run using:

```
easy_install gunicorn
```

however, it seems to be running python2. I tried

```
easy_install gunicorn3
```

but got an error. How can I use gunicorn with python3 on Mac OS X?

Edit: I was completely wrong in thinking the errors I was seeing were due to the use of python2. It's actually running 3.9 which is producing problems since so many packages are missing. I had earlier reverted to python 3.8. Is there a way to get gunicorn to use python3.8 as well? There error I'm seeing is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('gunicorn==20.0.4', 'console_scripts', 'gunicorn')())
  File "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", line 22, in importlib_load_entry_point
    for entry_point in distribution(dist_name).entry_points
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/metadata.py", line 524, in distribution
    return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/metadata.py", line 187, in from_name
    raise PackageNotFoundError(name)
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: gunicorn
```

Comment: Guicorn does work with python 3, I use it. All I did was ```python3 -m pip install guicorn``` Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks. It installed this way but looking closer, I think I was wrong in assuming it was running python2. It's actually trying to run python3.9 although I reverted to python3.8 since so many packages aren't working on 3.9 yet. Is there a way to get it use python3.8?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix this by uninstalling the egg installed by easy_install, then restarting the terminal and then just slightly modifying @Aiyush's answer to be:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall gunicorn
```

Simply using `pip install gunicorn` doesn't appear to work. I think I needed to restart the terminal in order for changes to ~/.bash_profile I had made days earlier to take effect.

Comment: In my case I had the python 3.8 version of gunicorn installed, and I ran `/usr/local/bin/pip3.7 install --upgrade --force-reinstall gunicorn` to replace it with the python 3.7 version.